# Download and save jpeg with Action Script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

Hi I need some guidance on how to download a jpeg image addressed through a URL, and save it to local disc using action script 3.

Most of the solutions Iv found require JPEG encoding libraries but I don't understand why I have to encode anything. The file is already in JPGE format, why do I need to download it as BitmapData only to use some bulky JPEG encoding class to turn it back into a jpeg again before I save it to disc?

I need a solution that bypasses this in-efficient approach please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to.

```
var stream:URLStream = new URLStream();
stream.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler );
stream.load( "URL TO JPG");

function completeHandler( e:Event ):void {
    var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    stream.readBytes( bytes );

    // use either FileStream or FileReference to save the byte array
}
```

When you load a JPG into `BitmapData`, it actually decompresses the JPG data. So that is why you can't save it directly... the JPG is no longer a JPG, it is an uncompressed Bitmap at that point. You can also load a BitmapData directly from a `ByteArray`, so you could also display the image if you needed to.

Comment: Thanks Apocalyptic0n3. Looking good so far but Im having trouble implementing that last part of your solution for saving the file. Could you finish it off please?

Comment: If this is a SWF for the web, use `FileReference.save( bytes, "filename.jpg" )`. If this is an AIR app, you can use `FileStream.writeBytes( bytes )` in conjunction with a `File`, though you should also be able to use FileReference, which gives the user the option to save the file where they want. Beyond that, do some searching. There are plenty of detailed examples on that part.

Comment: I tried to use FileReference but my code resulted in a "save file box" for the user to specify where to put the file. I need the code to save the file in same place as fla file automatically with no user input.

Comment: Just be careful since FileStream is *only* available for Adobe AIR applications and not available for SWFs used on the web. The ability to save to disk silently from the web is not possible with SWFs, other than through SharedObjects